# Merging dict DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge to Dictionaries on a common key (b). I am getting an output I would not expect:

The output from the pandas.merge is:
w
Int64Index([], dtype=int64)
Empty DataFrame

```
import pandas
#Create dictionaries
df1 = ({'a':[1], 'b':[2],'value1':[3]})

df2 = ({'b':[3], 'c':[4],'value2':[5]})

left=pandas.DataFrame(df1)
right=pandas.DataFrame(df2)

pandas.merge(left, right, on='b')
```

Looking for something like {‘a’:[1], ‘b’:[2,3], ‘c’:[4]}.

Comment: You say 'common key', but `left["b"]` and `right["b"]` have no values in common.  Could you edit your question to include the output frame you want?  (Maybe you want `outer`?)

Comment: @DSM. Adding how='outer' did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comments:

```
pandas.merge(left, right, on='b', how='outer')
```